# Streamlit Ports and Apache

Tags: apache, streamlit

I am trying to execute a streamlit file from PHP code.
`$port = "8502"; $command = escapeshellcmd("streamlit  run --server.port ".$port." python/Manager/Home.py $path $title_logo $userid"); $output = shell_exec($command);`

I have 3 files based on the conditions. The problem is that when I execute the file for the first time, it keeps the server busy and doesn't redirect to streamlit. It works when I kill Apache From XAMPP and restart it. I am passing User ID from PHP, which is being accessed from the session. For example, If i Login using user id = 1, i can see the data for the user. But if i login using user id = 2, the content doesn't update on streamlit. I checked the sys.argv values. It doesn't change there as well

Please it would be a great help if someone could help me fix this
Thank You